# Partial Outage in Apartment

Tags: circuit-breaker

Tonight half my apartment blacked out, the ceiling lights and the plugs on the bedroom and bathroom side of the apartment all were not working. I opened the circuit breaker box and flipped the switch that corresponded to the 5A and 25A (in the description it said "lights") switches. They originally were on "On" and I turned them both "Off", which resulted in my entire apartment becoming completely dark. I turned them back to "On" and the lights came back on, also the previously blacked out lights in the bedroom and bathroom and plugs are all working. My question is how did this happen and should I be concerned? My main concern is that, although the switches I flipped Off and back to On controlled the lights of the whole apartment, why did only part of my apartment go dark? Also, why were the switches set at "On" when I first checked? Sorry if this is confusing, please let me know!

Answer (score 4):

Most circuit breakers have 3 positions: On, Off, & Tripped. To a casual observer, the Tripped position may look like it is still "On". Note that you cannot move directly from Tripped to "On", you must go to "Off" first

[image]

https://www.anthonyphc.com/wp-content/uploads/tripped-circuit-breaker.jpg

Should you be concerned: Yes. It could have been a nuisance trip due to a momentary surge, but it could also be a real overcurrent condition. Inspect all the devices on this circuit. Look for frayed cords. If any of the devices are acting weird, replace them. If it happens again, call an electrician.

Did an incandescent bulb on this circuit recently burn out? Rarely, a broken filament will momentarily create a high current path.

Comment: It's also possible for the breaker to trip but _not_ move the handle! (Something I learned here just a few weeks ago.) That means that you could physically jam the handle into the "ON" position, but the breaker will still trip internally to protect your house. Moving the handle is a convenience for us to make it easier to find in the panel.